# BioPython Clades to Networkx labelled nodes

Tags: data-structures, networkx, biopython

I have a newick tree newick_tree_string = "(p1,(((((((p10,p5),p11),((p14,p6),p8)),p16),(((p12,p13),p15),p2)),p9),(p3,p7)),p4)"

And I need to get it into networkx form where the nodes are the "p_i". I tried reading it using BioPython:

```
tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(newick_tree_string), 'newick')
#name nameless clades
def tabulate_names(tree):
    names = {}
    for idx, clade in enumerate(tree.find_clades()):
        if clade.name:
            clade.name = clade.name
        else:
            clade.name = str(idx)
        names[clade.name] = clade
    return names
tabulate_names(tree)
G = Phylo.to_networkx(tree)
```

I have another networkx graph which I need to compare it to node by node:

```
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([('p17','p9'),('p17','p18'),('p17','p19'),('p19','p20'),('p9','p21'),('p21','p4'),('p21','p1'),('p9','p7'),('p7','p3'),('p20','p10'),('p20','p5'),('p19','p11'),('p19','p8'),('p8','p6'),('p8','p14'),('p18','p2'),('p18','p13'),('p18','p15'),('p18','p16'),('p13','p12')])
root_node = 17
```

The problem is that the first graph's nodes are of these weird 'clade' data_type which I can't use in functions with normal networkx graphs due to the different data structure. I need to turn the clades into nodes whilst keeping the same structure and names.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: From what I understand of your tree string, the pi are only the leaves of the tree, but you don't have names for the internal nodes of the tree. If you want to build a networkx graph you'll need to name these nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import networkx as nx
import io
from Bio import Phylo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your newick tree string
newick_tree_string = "(p1,(((((((p10,p5),p11),((p14,p6),p8)),p16),(((p12,p13),p15),p2)),p9),(p3,p7)),p4)"

# Read the tree using BioPython
tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(newick_tree_string), 'newick')

# Create a new NetworkX graph for the first tree
G = nx.Graph()

# Function to add nodes and edges based on the tree structure
def add_nodes_and_edges(clade):
    if clade.name:
        node_name = clade.name
    else:
        node_name = "Unnamed_Node"  # Assign a unique name if the node name is None
    G.add_node(node_name)
    for child in clade.clades:
        child_name = child.name if child.name else "Unnamed_Node"
        G.add_edge(node_name, child_name)
        add_nodes_and_edges(child)

# Start the recursive process to add nodes and edges
add_nodes_and_edges(tree.clade)

# Now you have the G graph in NetworkX format with labeled nodes
# Draw the first tree
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # Define the layout for better visualization
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='skyblue', font_size=10)
plt.title("First Tree Structure")
plt.show()

# Draw the second tree 'g'
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
pos_g = nx.spring_layout(g)  # Define the layout for better visualization
nx.draw(g, pos_g, with_labels=True, node_size=500, node_color='lightgreen', font_size=10)
plt.title("Second Tree Structure")
plt.show()

# Calculate the degree centrality of each node in the first tree 'G'
degree_centrality_G = nx.degree_centrality(G)
print("Degree centrality for the first tree:")
for node, centrality in degree_centrality_G.items():
    print(f"Node {node}: {centrality}")

# Calculate the shortest path length between two nodes in the first tree 'G'
shortest_path_length_G = nx.shortest_path_length(G, 'p1', 'p10')
print("Shortest path length in the first tree:", shortest_path_length_G)
```

[image]

u can check edge and node

```
import networkx as nx
import io
from Bio import Phylo

# Your newick tree string
newick_tree_string = "(p1,(((((((p10,p5),p11),((p14,p6),p8)),p16),(((p12,p13),p15),p2)),p9),(p3,p7)),p4)"

# Read the tree using BioPython
tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(newick_tree_string), 'newick')

# Convert the tree to NetworkX graph
G_phylo = Phylo.to_networkx(tree)

# Print the nodes of the NetworkX graph created from the Phylo tree
print("Nodes in Phylo tree graph:")
print(G_phylo.nodes())

# Print the edges of the NetworkX graph created from the Phylo tree
print("Edges in Phylo tree graph:")
print(G_phylo.edges())
```